# Mysql: How can I use RTRIM in my LOAD DATA INFILE query?

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

In my code I have a query that looks like this:

```
$load_query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$file}' INTO TABLE `{$table}`
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"';";
```

Here is an example row included in the file that I am trying to load:

```
"MC318199","06160","1","P","00750","00000","TN598792","04/16/2009","91X"
```

You will notice that at the end of the example row there are quite a few spaces. These spaces all occur before the new line character "\n" that terminates the line. The problem is that these spaces get entered into the database.

How can I remove the additional spaces when running the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command? Is there a way to use `RTRIM`?

**Edit**

As *ajreal* suggested I had to re-prepare the file. After the file was prepared it was inserted into the database correctly. I modified the bash script found at: http://gabeanderson.com/2008/02/01/unixlinux-find-replace-in-multiple-files/ to accomplish this. The code is shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash 
for fl in *.txt; do
  mv $fl $fl.old
  sed 's/[ \t]*$//' $fl.old > $fl
  rm -f $fl.old
done
```

Comment: I had to re-prepare the file before entering it into the database. I used the following bash script to remove the trailing spaces from the file. I posted the code in my question in order to be formatted properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dun think too complicate, right after u loaded the data 
`update $table set $last_column=rtrim($last_column);`

or manually remove the space in the $file using `vi` (or any editor)

or re-preapare the $file

Comment: Thanks for your help ajreal. As you suggested I had to re-prepare the file.

Answer (score 10):

```
$load_query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$file}' INTO TABLE `{$table}`
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' (col1, col2, ... , @col_with_spaces)
SET col_with_spaces = RTRIM(@col_with_spaces);";
```

That way you won't need to pre-process the file nor create other updates on the table.

Comment: hi, does it update the table after insertion of it trims in-memory. I want to use this but not at the cost of update after insertion.

Comment: This happens before insertion

Answer (score 2):

How about simply trimming the imported data in a second step?

```
$fix_query = "UPDATE `{$table}` SET LastFieldName = RTRIM(LastFieldName);";
```

Comment: Hi Tomalak, Thank you very much for your help. I realize that you did reply first, and your answer would've been right on. However, I found that I needed to strip the spaces before inserting the data - for some reason the spaces at the end of the file were causing an extra double quotation *"* mark to appear in the field. Thus I had to reprepare the file as ajreal suggested.

Answer (score 1):

use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`

```
$load_query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$file}' INTO TABLE `{$table}`
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' " ;
```

Comment: Cite *"These spaces all occur **before** the new line character `"\n"`"* ;-)

Comment: it's not space, it's CR symbol. Use "LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'"