# How to avoid white spaces being created while importing data from CSV file to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I am importing data from a CSV file into a MySQL table. When basic queries such as

```
 select * from Mapping where floor  = 'L1';
```

were not working, after lot of struggle I found that it is because of the white spaces and query

```
 select * from Mapping where floor  like '%L1%';
```

was giving me the expected results.

This is how I am loading my CSV to a table:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "../.../mapping.csv" INTO TABLE db.Mapping
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'   
    IGNORE 1 LINES
```

I am not sure where the white spaces are coming from? Am I loading my CSV in a correct manner? Is there something that I can do to avoid white spaces?

### Update

I have tried as per the answers,

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)                                                                                                                                
Rows matched: 49  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

It says no rows affected.

```
 select * from Mapping where floor  = 'L1';
```

is still not working, but

```
 select * from Mapping where floor  like '%L1%';
```

is giving the expected results.

Data of CSV file:

```
V,M,Floor
1,15,L1
2,14,L1
3,14,L1
4,16,L1
5,16,L1
6,6,L1
7,14,L1
8,13,L1
9,12,L1
10,11,L1
11,16,L1
```

Comment: See "Input Preprocessing" in the [manuals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

Comment: See the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162362/mysql-how-can-i-use-rtrim-in-my-load-data-infile-query)

Comment: You might want to share a few lines of sample data, which results in records causing you trouble.

Comment: I have a csv file, is it possible to attach a csv file here?

Comment: @Abecee added same data

Comment: You might want to for non-printing characters, e.g., `SELECT *, LENGTH(floor) FROM Mapping WHERE floor  LIKE '%L1%';`.

Comment: length(floor) is 3 for all the rows. Is should be 2 right ?

Comment: Did trimming resolve the issue?

Comment: No, I altered the position of columns, put floor as second and M as third column. There wasn't any issue then

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I advocate loading data into staging tables where all columns are strings and then doing to cleaning in the database.

However, `load data infile` does have some nice features for cleaning data.  If your extra characters are spaces, you can use `trim()`.  The key is variables and `SET`:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "../.../mapping.csv"
    INTO TABLE db.Mapping 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'   
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (@floor, . . . )  -- list the rest of the columns here
    SET floor = TRIM(@floor);
```

If the errors are more complicated, then regular expressions are helpful:

```
SET floor = REGEXP_REPLACE(@floor, '[^A-Z0-9]', '')
```

Comment: Not sure if that matters - but according to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) the column list should come right before `SET`

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE` is not working in my version of MySQL ->`mysqld  Ver 5.7.28-0`

Answer (score 1):

You could always trim the whitespace after the data is inserted;

```
UPDATE db.Mapping SET floor = trim(floor);
```